# Use the Residue Theorem to evaluate.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, vectors

Use the residue theorem to evaluate the integral, $$\int_{|z|=2}ze^{\frac{3}{z}}dz.$$
Note: To start this, I understand I likely will have the easiest time finding the residue using the essential singularity $e^{\frac{3}{z}}$ and directly finding the Laurent expansion but $z$ complicates this. What should I do?

Comment: Can you write down the Laurent expansion? You might find it easier after doing the change of variables $z \mapsto 1/z$.

Comment: @davidlowryduda The integral can be interpreted as the definition of Laurent expansion coefficients :D

Answer (score 1):

$z=0$ is only the singularity here. Then  the Laurent expansion at $x=0$ is given by $ze^{(3/z)}=z(1+(3/z)/1!+(3/z)^2/2!+.....).$
What is the residue at this singularity? Can you complete?

Answer (score 0):

Due to Cauchy's theorem, we can make the contour's radius arbitrarily large. This enables us too study the integral via series expansions:

It is known that when $x$ is near zero, $e^x$ satisfies

$$
e^x=1+x+{x^2\over2}+\mathcal O(x^3)
$$

This indicates that when $|z|\to+\infty$ there is

$$
e^{3/z}=1+\frac3z+{9\over2z^2}+\mathcal O\left(1\over z^3\right)
$$

Plugging this asymptotic expansion into the original problem, we get

\begin{aligned}
\oint_{|z|=2}ze^{3/z}\mathrm dz
&=\oint_{|z|=R}\left(z+3+{9\over2z}\right)\mathrm dz+\oint_{|z|=R}\mathcal O\left(1\over z^2\right)\mathrm dz \\
&=2\pi i\cdot\frac92+\mathcal O\left(\frac1R\right)
\end{aligned}

Now, let $R\to+\infty$, so we deduce

$$
\oint_{|z|=2}ze^{3/z}\mathrm dz=9\pi i
$$